# Show unique contact logs for each day and show the count on one side

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts

I need to show contact logs in my `Android` application in a `ListView` with the `section headers.`

```
     while (curLog.moveToNext()) {
              String callNumber = curLog.getString( curLog.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
               conNumbers.add(callNumber);

              String callName = curLog.getString( curLog.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
               conNames.add(callName);

              String callType = curLog.getString(curLog.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
                    String dir = null;
                    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
                    switch (dircode) {
                        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                            dir = "Outgoing";
                            break;

                        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                            dir = "Incoming";
                            break;

                        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                            dir = "Missed";
                            break;
                    }

                 conType.add(dir);
           String callDate = curLog.getString( curLog.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
           SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
           String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(callDate)));
           condateTime.add(dateString);
}
```

I got all the values. **Consider For "today" i got 2 missed calls from same number. Instead of showing the number twice for the day. I need unique logs for each day and show the count on one side.**

How can we implement that?

Comment: hint: you can use a hashmap to store entries and to keep the track of repetition

Comment: Thanks Pavneet Singh. Can you please brief?.

Comment: buddy you need to do filtering on many factors,many solutions can be there so u need to work on. first maintain a daygroup for entries based on their date then every daygroup need to filter on the basis of first number then on next level filter on call type so now for every new entry look for day then number entry under that day then call type entry under that number then maintain a count against that day+ number+type entry

Comment: I have filtered the section with each day results. But i cant able to get the count for the duplication in a day,